# FactoryGirl and RSpec Not Rolling Back

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

A simple pre-generated test is not working. It's been changed to be as more simple but the data is not being reverted after the test. So the first time it runs, passes, then fails every subsequent with the count going up.

I'm running on a Mac, with MariaDb installed with an innoDB engine.

rails_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

Factories

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :tag do
    icon
    word
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :word do
    word 'TestWord'
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :icon do
    icon_name "Cool Icon"
    icon_location "cache/1234"
    submission_date "2014-12-15 18:38:20"
  end
end
```

Spec

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe TagsController, type: :controller do

  # let(:tag) {  build(:tag) }
  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  describe "GET #index" do
    it "assigns all tags as @tags" do
      @tag = FactoryGirl.create(:tag)
      get :index, {}, valid_session
      expect(Tag.count).to eq([@tag].count)
    end
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **DataBaseCleaner** gem:

Include this line in your Gemfile: `gem 'database_cleaner'`, and run `bundle install`.

Then, include this lines in the **Spec.configure** block:

```
config.before(:suite) do
  begin
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.start
    FactoryGirl.lint
  ensure
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Hope this help :)